# Jupyter Notebook and virtualenv

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Jupyter notebook and use it with a virtualenv, I already have installed some packages in python but when I run in Jupyter notebook for example import numpy as np, I have a issue, module not found, there are a way to connect all of my python installed packages with Jupyter notebook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To access the packages within your environment you have to register the kernel with jupyter.

1. Switch to your virtual environment.
2. install ipykernel `pip install ipykernel`
3. pass the virtual environment name to the following command
   `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=[name of your environment]`
4. launch jupyter `jupyter notebook`
5. select your notebook
6. In the menu under your notebook name select kernel>change kernel>[name of your environment]

As below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `jupyter notebook` command may not be referencing to the jupyter installation in the virutal environment you are using. This is why even though you might have installed packages in your environment, jupyter is unable to import them because it is looking at a different place.

You could try to set up a different kernel for your environment, but I find that task to be tedious and after a while it becomes hard to keep track of your kernels.

The best way would be to start jupyter notebook with the python environment where all your modules are installed. To do this, activate your virtual environment, and then do:

```
python -m jupyter notebook
```

This will open Jupyter with the jupyter installed in the place where your `python` is pointing to and it will have the packages installed there!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider:

1. Have you installed those modules inside the virtual env?
2. Are you launching jupyter from inside the virtual env?

If you perform those actions correctly, then the error should go away.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

If you installed your packages in python and launched your jupyter notebook from your virtualenv, you cannot import those installed packages because virtualenv created an isolated Python environment. You can read about virtualenv [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/).

There are two ways to resolve your problem:

1. Launch jupyter notebook without virtualenv (simply type `jupyter notebook` in your terminal / command prompt)
2. Install those packages inside your virtual environment.